# How to (or is it possible to) use a list to extract nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary like this in Python:

```
d = {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": {
        "nk1": "v2"
    },
    "k3": "v3"
}
```

I have a list which stores which key I want to extract and some of them are nested keys:

```
extract = ["k1", "nk1", "k3"]
```

Or I can define it in this way to show that `nk1` is nested in `k2`, and I don't need the value for "k2" since it's just a nested dictionary:

```
extract = ["k1", ["k2", "nk1"], "k3"]
```

Is there a way to loop through this `extract` list and get all the values I needed or is there are simpler way to check if a key exists in a nested dictionary?

Ideal output is a dictionary:

```
r = {
    "k1": "v1",
    "nk1": "v2",
    "k3": "v3"
}
```

Comment: But now `k2` is "gone" in your *ideal output*? Furthermore what if a key is present multiple times in the subdictionary?

Comment: Would you just like to flatten you dict?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `k2` is gone because eventually I want `nk1` within `k2`. The second extract list is just a path to the final key I want. Duplicates shouldn't exist if I use the second extract structure since I can specify the exact path to the key-value.

Comment: @d_kennetz I got duplicate key names within the dict, but I don't want to make a whole new dict since I will need to perform this on over X00K number of dictionaries.

Comment: I see, a bit more challenging then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` to get the value specified by the given list of keys:

```
from functools import reduce
dict((k[-1], reduce(dict.get, k, d)) if isinstance(k, list) else (k, d[k]) for k in extract)
```

Given your sample input, this returns:

```
{'k1': 'v1', 'nk1': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, we can use recursion here:

```
def linearize(some_dict):
    result = {}
    def lin(subdic):
        for k, v in subdic.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                lin(v)
            else:
                result[k] = v
    lin(some_dict)
    return result
```

this yields:

```
>>> linearize(d)
{'k1': 'v1', 'nk1': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
```

Note however that since in case of a subdictionary the corresponding key is "ignored", this thus means that we "lose information" to reconstruct the original dictionary.

If multiple subdictionaries contain the same key, the value of the last one will be used. So it is possible that the result dictionary contains *less* key-value items, than the (sub)dictionaries of the original dictionary.

**EDIT**: you can also make an extraction as follows:

```
def extract(some_dict, to_extract):
    result = {}
    def ext(ky):
        if isinstance(ky, str):
            ky = (ky,)
        subd = some_dict
        for k in ky:
            subd = subd[k]
        result[k] = subd
    for ky in to_extract:
        ext(ky)
    return result
```

then we obtain:

```
>>> extract(d, ["k1", ["k2", "nk1"], "k3"])
{'k1': 'v1', 'nk1': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
```

Comment: This is essentially flattening the dictionary, which is not what I want as I only need like 5 keys from the original dictionary which has like 100 keys. This will take way too much space and I had to have another filter to go through it.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Though I decided to go with the one-liner from blhsing, but this also works and it's easier to understand as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
d = {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": {
        "nk1": "v2"
    },
    "k3": "v3"
}
extract = ["k1", "nk1", "k3"]

def get_possibly_nested_key(k, d):
    # k = key
    # d = dict
    if isinstance(k, list) and len(k) > 1:
        return get_possibly_nested_key(k[1:], d[k[0]])
    else:
        if isinstance(k, list):
            return d[k[0]]
        return d[k]

result = [get_possibly_nested_key(e, d) for e in extract]
print(result)
```